# Netbeans - exclude .svn directories from editor

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1 and for some reason in the "Projects" view the .svn directories are showing up alongside the source code. How can I tell NetBeans to not show the .svn directories?

I believe it worked like this when I first installed NetBeans but somehow it's started showing the .svn directories (I likely mucked up a setting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually set up like this by default, but you must have changed it.
In the menu Tools / Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files you should have a "ignored by the IDE" pattern looking like

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!lib|htaccess$).*$
```

This is my setting, I have added the last htaccess part to show .htaccess files in the project window.

You can see the default pattern at http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/file_types_UI_spec/

Comment: thanks...I think I cleared that setting when I added a new file type. I didn't realize the "ignored by IDE" applied globally, when i saw it initially I though it was linked to a file extension (which doesn't make any sense :)